# Next.js "_framerMotion.motion.custom is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion, chakra-ui

I have a problem with Chakra UI in Next.js. I have installed all packages normally. And I have edited the _app.tsx.

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

But when I trying to start the development server, it gives me an error like this:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
event - compiled successfully
event - build page: /
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
event - build page: /next/dist/pages/_error
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
error - TypeError: _framerMotion.motion.custom is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/Projects/nextjs-chakraui/node_modules/@chakra-ui/checkbox/dist/cjs/checkbox-icon.js:20:38)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/Projects/nextjs-chakraui/node_modules/@chakra-ui/checkbox/dist/cjs/checkbox.js:14:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/Projects/nextjs-chakraui/node_modules/@chakra-ui/checkbox/dist/cjs/index.js:13:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
TypeError: _framerMotion.motion.custom is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/Projects/nextjs-chakraui/node_modules/@chakra-ui/checkbox/dist/cjs/checkbox-icon.js:20:38)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/Projects/nextjs-chakraui/node_modules/@chakra-ui/checkbox/dist/cjs/checkbox.js:14:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/Projects/nextjs-chakraui/node_modules/@chakra-ui/checkbox/dist/cjs/index.js:13:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
```

Please help me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 9):

https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/3618 says you should downgrade framer-motion

-> in package.json: change "framer-motion": "x.y.z" to "framer-motion": "3.10.6"

-> npm install

**UPDATE:** This issue has been resolved since, see https://chakra-ui.com/guides/integrations/with-framer for more info.

Comment: Answer is misleading, presumably needs to reflect update

Comment: @AveryFreeman As far as I know this issue has been resolved since. I've updated my answer, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5):

If someone else using Chakra-UI accidentally invokes `motion.custom()` due to outdated documentation, *do not downgrade to 3.10.6*.  Find out what the proper syntax for v4 is instead.

`motion.custom()` *has been depreciated*, but the developers have added support for Framer Motion v4:  https://chakra-ui.com/guides/integrations/with-framer

Solutions are quite a bit more elegant and simple to implement as a result.

From v4-updated documentation re: depreciation of `motion.custom()`,

> If you're using the latest version of framer motion, which is >= v
> 3.10.0. In this version, framer-motion automatically filters out motion-related props forwarded to the provided component.

That means, in most cases, anything stating that `forwardRef` and `isValidMotionProp` are required to forward and filter motion-related props to a component *is what is actually depreciated*.

For instance, say we have the following component we to be able to drag around the screen:

```
const DraggyBox = () => {
  return (
    <MotionBox
      boxSize="40px"
      bg="green.600"
      drag
      dragPropagation
      dragMomentum={false}
      whileHover={{ scale: 1.2 }}
      whileTap={{ scale: 0.8 }}
    />
  )
}
```

In `v3 > 3.10.0` with `motion.custom()`, you'd have to write this to be able to achieve it:

```
import { Box, forwardRef } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { motion, isValidMotionProp } from "framer-motion"

const MotionBox = motion.custom(
  forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const chakraProps = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(props).filter(([key]) => !isValidMotionProp(key)),
    )
    return <Box ref={ref} {...chakraProps} />
  }),
)
```

While now, in `v3 >= 3.10.0 (v4)`, `motion()` achieves the same result with far less syntax:

```
import { Box } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { motion } from "framer-motion"

const MotionBox = motion(Box)
```

Moral of story:  Don't go downgrading before doing your research - you might end up giving yourself a lot more work in the long run!