# ReactJS framer_motion__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.motion.custom is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I am using chakraUI in my react project and I am getting the following error:

```
chakra-ui-checkbox.esm.js:146 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: framer_motion__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.motion.custom is not a function
    at Module../node_modules/@chakra-ui/checkbox/dist/chakra-ui-checkbox.esm.js (chakra-ui-checkbox.esm.js:146:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at Module../node_modules/@chakra-ui/react/dist/chakra-ui-react.esm.js (chakra-ui-react-utils.esm.js:91:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at Module../src/App.js (bundle.js:18:74)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

**Here is how I used this in my app.js file**

```
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/navbar";
import { useState } from "react";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import theme from "./theme";
function App() {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <ChakraProvider>
        <Navbar isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen} setIsMenuOpen={setIsMenuOpen} />
      </ChakraProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.7",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "framer-motion": "^6.2.8",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66703410/next-js-framermotion-motion-custom-is-not-a-function) is one of the solution for it but I thought this issue was fixed. So what is the issue with my code. Can someone please help?

Comment: I juuuust had this crop up in my application all of the sudden as well. Not sure what I changed to make it happen. Only is triggering via cypress tests. Not seeing it in local dev env.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the blue I also had this exact same issue at the same time you were having it and I tracked it down to the webpack version floating up and causing issues.

Pinning the webpack version at 5.70 has fixed this issue for me. It had floated to 5.71. I haven't looked into what was in that change to have caused this issue.

Comment: how did you fix webpack version?

Comment: Sorry, by 'fixed' I meant I kept the version from floating. Out of the blue the floating webpack version caused this exact issue for me. So I stopped it from going to 5.71 by pinning the version at 5.70 and the error went away. I've edited the answer to be more clear. This may or may not be the trouble you were facing, it could certainly be a coincidence that within hours of me having this issue I found your question.